Replacing rotten rim boards on deck
Those black double 1x8 have rotted at all corners and I need to replace them:


I think I can handle the demo part, cutting new boards to size and nailing them back onto the stringer.
I may have to replace the guard posts (4x4), or at the very least take down and then put back on, because they overlap the rim boards and punch through them.


I can get new posts and cut them to size. But there are a few things I am not clear on:

Should I put those large "screws" back through the same holes?
What tool do I need to take them out or screw them back in?
How should I even approach this?

I am not sure what the process is here. I am thinking:

Take down everything - posts, boards, strip it down to stringer and step boards
Nail on the 1x8s
Drill through the 1x8s, to match the holes in the stringer behind them
Mark holes on the new 4x4 posts (how am I even going to match perfectly the line of drilling)
Drill through the 4x4
Put screws back in, through the post, through the board, through the stringer

What is the correct process here? Thanks.

I would suggest hitting up your favorite online video hosting site and searching for "deck stair reconstruction" or something similar. There are bound to be 100s of videos that will walk you through the overall process. Then you can come here to ask a very specific question about a single step that still has you confused. I am thinking, though, that if you don't know what tool is necessary to remove a nut from a bolt, you might want to start your DIY career on something that's a little less... life critical should it fail. You'll get there, but this may not be the ideal starter project.

No need to be condescending, I wasn't referring to the nut, but about how the bolt is driven. Thanks for your suggestions.

You undo the nuts on the inside, then drive the bolts back through the hole with a hammer, same way they were installed. These are carriage bolts - there's a square shoulder under the head that prevents them from spinning. No condensention intended - not only is your question overly broad, but where detail was provided, it wasn't clear what you were asking about. Good communication is hard (married 34 years, still working on it daily).

Ok thanks for your help. If I am to focus on a single question, that would be - after I take apart everything, do I put the bolts back in through the same holes that were left. Basically drill through the new rim board and new post (from behind, using the stringer hole as a guide) and reinstall the bolts, right? (Married for 20).

You just want to replace the skirting boards, right—stringers remain?

Correct. Or a rim-board, whatever it's called. The stringers are fine.

You can get carriage bolts in nearly any length you want, you don't have to use those long ones. Since you have them already, you might as well reuse them.
You can take the existing ones off by removing the nut (I don't see a nut on the bottom one in the picture - maybe it's embedded in the wood because the washer is missing?) with a wrench or socket. Pros would use an impact driver, but it'd need a very deep socket due to the length of carriage bolt. Once the nut is off, tap it with a hammer from the backside until it dislodges the head of the carriage bolt. You might have someone hold the weight of the post so it's not binding the bolt as it's coming out.
Cutting a new 4x4 post with the proper notches will be kind of challenging, but to get the holes to line up properly you can clamp the new notched post in place and drill from the backside through the existing holes in the stringers. You could alternatively do something to mark through the stringer holes, like a long thin pencil, some spray paint, or something like that, then bring the posts down and drill the holes based on the markings.
Definitely use washers next to the nuts on the inside of the stringers when you reinstall, in case that bottom nut pulled into the wood. The washers spread out the force on the bolt and nuts across the wood near it. Posts should really have extra reinforcement if you can figure out how to install and properly support one of these (Simpson tension tie) - a pair of bolts even with solid stringers and washers usually doesn't cut it for long.


If I repair and reuse the posts, that should generally make it easier, right? I wouldn't have to chisel notches. I'll just have to punch through the new skirt between the post and the stringer.

Can I attach the Simpson tie to a riser?  There's no joist around.

The dtt doesn’t attach to a riser. Put solid blocking (2x material) between the stringers and attach the dtt to that.
